# Interesting articles on "Notices of the AMS" or "MMA" about differential and Riemannian geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

Can you give reference and explain some interesting articles on "Notices of the AMS" or "The American Mathematical Monthly" about differential and Riemannian geometry  have you ever read?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why only the *Notices of the AMS*?

Comment: Because it is easy to read for undergraduate and graduate.

Comment: Is there other magazine  for undergraduate and graduate student ?

Comment: I added "The American Mathematical Monthly".

Comment: What about *Mathematics Magazine* or *The Mathematical Gazette*?

Comment: That's Ok. every good magazine that you know !

Answer (score 1):

A classic exposition is:

> Anderson, Michael T. "Geometrization of 3-manifolds via the Ricci flow." *Notices AMS* 51 (2004): 184-193.
>   ([PDF download](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~anderson/noticesfinal.pdf).)
>
> ---
>
> [image: Horns]

---

"The work of Perelman builds on prior work of
Thurston and Hamilton. In the next two sections
we discuss the Thurston picture of 3-manifolds and
the Ricci flow introduced and analyzed by Hamilton."